# window.requestFileSystem and window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL fail on some devices

Tags: android, cordova, html5-filesystem

It's been a while since we noticed some users can't download anything. Finally, yesterday I detected that it's due to the `filesystem` not being initalized on some devices (some of them returned a `cannot access property root of null`).

I've tried doing this:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
    function(fileSystem){

    },
    function() {

    }
);
```

and

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(specific_path,
    function(parentEntry) {

    },
    function() {

    }
);
```

And in any of my devices (or any of the office devices), it simply works. However, some users seem to always fall on the error. I wait to do this on the `onDeviceReady`, and it is even wrapped in a `ready` listener.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});
```

Can you think of a cause to this, or is it a known bug? I've checked it and I couldn't find any.

I'm using Cordova 3.7.1 and File plugin 1.3.3.

PS:

In case you wonder what `specific_path` is, it's a tailored list of possible paths per OS, ordered by our preference. The Android list is:

- "file:///storage/extSdCard/Android/data/*package_name*"
- cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory
- cordova.file.externalDataDirectory
- cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory
- cordova.file.dataDirectory
- cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "*package_name*"